# Suggested edits proposed by an anonymous user?

Tags: support

Recently I started reviewing suggested edits, and while reviewing I found lots of suggested edits were "proposed x hour ago by an anonymous user", this piqued my curiosity, I wonder who this anonymous user is;

Is the anonymous user the Community user?

I just found out that I can still click edit while I was logged out, so I think suggest edits proposed by an anonymous user were proposed while no account was logged in, is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Is the anonymous user the Community user?

No:

> Anyone on the internet can suggest edits. When someone without a Stack Overflow account does this, then the resulting suggested edit is recorded as anonymous (but moderators can see the IP address).

However:

> When the suggested edit is accepted, the suggestion results in an actual change, a revision to the post. That resulting revision is attributed to Community. That's because all revisions on the site must have a valid user account associated with them, so Community is 'blamed'.

Source: [what does mean for proposed yesterday by an anonymous user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360556/3536342), answer by [Martijn Pieters ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)

So a not logged in user proposes the edit and if it gets accepted it is attributed to the community user.